# Uso da vírgula antes de ‘e’, ‘ou’, ‘mas’

Tags: pontuação, conjunções

É necessário usar sempre vírgula antes das conjunções ‘e’, ‘ou’, e ‘mas’, ou depende do contexto?

**e**

> Comprou cartas **e** selos.
>   Foi ao café, pediu um bolo, leu os títulos do jornal, **e** ainda conversou com o pai da Josefa.

**mas**

> Trouxeram-no **mas** já morto.
>   Ela bem que insistia com ele, **mas** ele pouco lhe ligava.

**ou**

> Teria de escolher entre um **ou** outro.
>   Vais agora buscar a encomenda, **ou** ainda tens de voltar ao escritório?

Em algum destes exemplos a vírgula está a mais, ou a menos?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As conjunções 'e', 'ou' e 'mas', quando listam elementos de igual valor sintático, não dever ser acompanhadas de vírgula:

> Comprou cartas **e** selos.
>
> Teria de escolher entre um **ou** outro.
>
> Não só João **mas** também Maria correram.

[Fonte 1](http://revistalingua.com.br/textos/67/artigo249104-1.asp) | [Fonte 2](http://revistaescola.abril.com.br/fundamental-2/sempre-devo-usar-virgula-antes-palavra-669205.shtml)

Quando as conjunções 'ou' e 'mas' separam orações, utiliza-se a vírgula:

> Vais agora buscar a encomenda, **ou** ainda tens de voltar ao escritório?
>
> Ela bem que insistia com ele, **mas** ele pouco lhe ligava.
>
> Trouxeram-no(,) **mas** já morto. → *É necessária a vírgula, pois separa-se duas orações distintas: "trouxeram-no, mas (ele) já (estava) morto.*

Já a conjunção 'e', ao separar orações, só pede vírgula quando o sujeito se altera de uma oração para outra. Em outras palavras, quando se pode gerar ambiguidade quanto ao sujeito das orações:

> Foi ao café, pediu um bolo, leu os títulos do jornal<strike>,</strike> **e** ainda conversou com o pai da Josefa. → *Não é necessária a vírgula, pois o sujeito (ele) continua o mesmo.*
>
> João toca piano, **e** Maria, violão.

[Fonte](http://educacao.uol.com.br/dicas-portugues/virgula-antes-do-e-so-em-casos-especiais.jhtm)

Comment: *Teria de escolher entre um ou outro.* Acho que esta frase está incorreta, "entre" já indica que nós estamos a referir a uma escolha, deveria ser *Teria de escolher entre um e outro.*

Comment: Não concordo. Ela pode não ser perfeitamente lógica, mas continua sendo uma frase possível do português. A frase "mato passarinhos e depois eles voam" pode não fazer sentido, mas continua sendo correta. A frase estaria incorreta se fosse agramatical, ou se não estivesse de acordo com as normas de grafia.

Comment: Acho mesmo que gramaticalmente está incorreta porque o "entre" já faz de "ou". Mas não tenho a certeza.

Comment: [É correto escrever “entre um ou outro”?](http://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/698/%C3%89-correto-escrever-entre-um-ou-outro)