# É correto escrever "entre um ou outro"?

Tags: conjugações

[Nesta resposta](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/a/697/153) surgiu a dúvida se esta frase está correta:

> Teria de escolher entre um **ou** outro.

Eu estou acostumado a usar **e** em vez de **ou** quando uso *entre* na frase:

> Teria de escolher entre um **e** outro.

É correto escrever ***entre um ou outro***?

Comment: Acho que se trata mais de estilística, mas vou gostar de ler as respostas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A minha inclinação é que a frase deve ser "entre um **e** outro".

A preposição "entre" escolhe entre duas (ou mais) coisas. Mas "A ou B" significa¹ uma das três possibilidades seguintes:

1. A e não B
2. B e não A
3. A e B

<sup>¹ no sentido de [disjunção inclusiva](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silogismo_disjuntivo)</sup>

Dizendo "entre um *ou* outro" parece que só há a possibilidade de escolha no caso (3), então eu acho que "entre um **e** outro" é mais natural.

---

Verifiquei no [CRPC](http://www.clul.ul.pt/pt/investigador/183-reference-corpus-of-contemporary-portuguese-crpc) (Corpus de Referência do Português Contemporâneo), e de fato a frase "entre um **e** outro" é a mais usada:

```
entre um e outro   159 resultados
entre um ou outro    5 resultados
entre um e o outro   3 resultados
```

Pelo menos *estatisticamente*, a frase "entre um **e** outro" é mais correta do que "entre um ou outro". ;)

Comment: A mim parece-me *entre (A ou B) e C* parece que continua a faltar o "e ____".

Comment: O link está quebrado.

Comment: @BellAppLab Qual? Os dois estão funcionando aqui. (As vezes a página do CRPC precisa de um "refresh"; o corpus mesmo está [aqui](http://alfclul.clul.ul.pt/CQPweb/crpcfg15/).)

Comment: O CRPC custa a abrir de fato. De qualquer maneira, de acordo com o CPRC, `Os textos incluídos no CRPC pertencem maioritariamente à variedade europeia do Português`. Tenho para comigo que o português europeu é mais rígido no sentido das palavras, digo, sintaticamente. Já o português brasileiro é mais flexível nas redundâncias. Por exemplo, é comum nas Minas Gerais se dizer: "oia p'r'ocê vê" (olha para você ver).

Comment: @BellAppLab isso é uma questão de sotaque ou de falar mal português?

Comment: @JorgeB. Nem um nem outro, na minha opinião. Acho que se trata de pragmática, ou seja, de como os falantes da língua a utilizam para comunicação. https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pragmática

Answer (score 5):

Uma questão de estilo e preferência.  "Escolher entre um e outro/Escolher entre um ou outro" são ambos de uso corrente dependendo de onde você esteja.  Regionalismos existem mas neste caso em particular eu ouço as duas formas na região em que vivo. Pessoalmente eu uso "entre um e outro", acho que devido ao cacófato "ouou".

Answer (score 1):

Pois bem, eu sou professor de língua portuguesa e tive essa dúvida sobre o uso da preposição entre e suas colocações. Inicialmente, fiz uma análise de sentido e isso depende às vezes do verbo a ser usado antes de tal preposição, veja:
"Ele teve que escolher entre o fogo ou a água." Aqui o verbo escolher faz com que o "ou" da frase esteja bem empregado, pois se trata de um "ou" com sentido de exclusão, uma vez que não se pode escolher coisas que se opõem como fogo e água. Haveria algum problema nesse tipo de frase se o "ou" fosse inclusivo. Isso quer dizer que o "ou" inclusivo aceita a possibilidade de duas coisas ocorrerem ao mesmo tempo. Veja:
"Acho que ela precisa decidir entre mandar beijinho ou dar tchauzinho." Aqui o "ou" possui sentido de inclusão, esse "ou" possibilita a ocorrência das duas coisas, uma vez que ela pode decidir dar beijinho e dar tchauzinho. Em tal caso há ruído de sentido no uso do "ou", sendo melhor usar o "e".
Pesquisando mais afundo, não há erro em usar "entre a ou b" quando o "ou" tiver sentido de exclusão. Mas poderá haver algum ruído de sentido no uso "entre a ou b" quando o "ou" possibilitar o sentido de inclusão. Então, recomendo que façam inicialmente uma análise de sentido quando forem usar o par "entre ou".
Em última análise, o dicionário Caldas Aulete de língua portuguesa trás o seguinte exemplo sobre o verbo optar em que aparece o par "entre ou": "optar v. ti. Escolher; decidir-se por ( algo entre duas ou mais possibilidades). Então, o uso de "entre ou" não é errado. Todavia, é muito comum o uso do par "entre e" porque em tal uso não precisamos fazer análise de sentido. Espero ter contribuído de alguma forma.